# fusion table in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I use fusion table with Google API.
I want to add event of click that will raise a message.
When I press on click I got message box with all the information from the fusion table.
Can I control on this message Box and use the data to show different message box?
Can I disable the message Box ?

Regards,
Yossi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing a link to your page or your code I can't tell you that these snippets can be dropped in and will work for you, however suppressing the infowindows isn't difficult, and can be added after you define the layer map.

An example snippet is:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(1264600, {suppressInfoWindows: true});
layer.setQuery("SELECT geometry FROM 1264600");
layer.setMap(map);
```

Creating a custom info window when a user clicks on the map based on data from the table can then be accomplished like this:

```
//click listener on layer
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
map.setZoom(7);
if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
else infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //create info window layer
    infoWindowContent = infowindow.setContent(
        '<h3>This comes from the Fusion Table: <br />' + e.row['NAMELSAD10'].value + '</h3>' +
        '<br />' +
        '<p>This is hardcoded to the script <br /> and will appear in each infowindow</p>');

    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    map.setCenter(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);        
});
```

Putting it all together you get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chrislkeller/rYfwm/6/

Hope this helps, and please post some code if you run into more questions...

Chris K.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to create custom info windows using Fusion tables.  There is a page in the help documentation that describes how to do this.

http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171216

Check out the "Create a custom template" Heading

Comment: I want just to control on the click in the map.I am using the google maps API and to color the country.How I can disbale the info windows that will not show all the data ?